# Use polyline in google-maps-react?

Tags: react-google-maps

I am using **google-maps-react** in my react program.
 Is there any way to draw **polyline** between the plotted markers 
any in-bulid method to make line between the markers

Comment: try this https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#directionsrenderer just a suggestion tho.

Comment: The OP mentions using `google-maps-react`, yet all the answers provided are for `react-google-maps`. Two different components. All the answers should be downvoted for not adhering to what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Import Polyline from react-google-maps and then inside your `<GoogleMap></GoogleMap>` place something like:

```
<Polyline 
  path={pathCoordinates} 
  options={{ 
  strokeColor: '#00ffff',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  icons: [{ 
    icon: "hello",
    offset: '0',
    repeat: '10px'
  }],
}}
/>
```

And then pass some locations to `pathCoordinates` e.g.

```
pathCoordinates:[ 
  {lat:50, lng:1},
  {lat:50.1, lng:1.1},
]
```

Comment: but, how to add `Polyline ` on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can all you need to do is add the points to your path inside the options.

```
<Polyline   geodesic={true}
            options={{
                path: props.route,
                strokeColor: '#00ffff',
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 6,
                icons: [{
                    offset: '0',
                    repeat: '10px'
                }],
            }}
 />
```

where props.route looks something like this

```
[   
    {"lat": 3.028846373870724, "lng": 101.62019493865353},
    {"lat": 3.0293392107899226, "lng": 101.62000181960445},
    {"lat": 3.0297677644503347, "lng": 101.61980870055538},
    {"lat": 3.0301963179410842, "lng": 101.61967995452267},
    {"lat": 3.0307105819060256, "lng": 101.6194868354736},
    {"lat": 3.0319319578431805, "lng": 101.61916497039181}
]
```